# XSL not returning value but instead &#10

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I'm new to XSL and trying to transform an existing xml. The existing xml looks like this:

```
<doc>
  <hierarchy>
    <item id="3C0F19D7AF2578304" level="7" name="myFile.xls" url="https://www.example.com">
    </item>
  <hierarchy>
</doc>
```

I'd like to get the `<item id>` and add it to a new element `<add id>`. When I use XSL the output is a string of `&#10`s

The XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/doc">
    <add >
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="hierarchy/item[@id]" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </add>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The ouput from this looks like this:

```
<add id="&#10;      &#10;        &#10;        &#10;        &#10;        &#10;        &#10;        &#10;      &#10;    ">
```

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="hierarchy/item/@id"/>`

Comment: Ha! So easy. Thanks for the quick reply. What is the [@whatever] used for?

Comment: @OliverBurdekin Lookup *predicate*.